# ¿Como hacer para que el texto ajuste su tamaño segun el tamaño de la pantalla en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design

Buenas, he estado trabajando en un proyecto que realmente es básico por tal motivo he tratado de que tenga un buen diseño y sea soportado en varias apis.

Con respecto a vistas como botones, linearlayous estoy manejándolas con la propiedad weight para que se puedan ajustar a la pantalla.

Ahora que pasa con el texto, esto no se puede hacer con textos.

Entonces quiera que me echaran una mano con aquello de que el texto ajuste su tamaño segun la pantalla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es similar a como se realiza para los layouts, defines dentro del folder de determinada densidad valores en sp correspondientes:

> ```
> res/values/dimens.xml
>
> res/values-small/dimens.xml
>
> res/values-normal/dimens.xml
>
> res/values-large/dimens.xml
>
> res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
> ```

Por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">19sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Este valor lo lees y lo defines en tu `TextView` o vista a la cual desees configurar el tamaño texto :

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
```

Comment: ES necesario colocar ese codigo java, yo creia que el equipo seleccionaba la carpeta small, large, xlarge, segun la densidad de la pantalla.

Comment: El codigo lo que realiza es definir el valor de dimens pero el sistema operativo toma el correspondiente de los folders, puedes también definirlo directamente en la vista definida en el layout.