# Tengo que crear un Values/dimens.xml para cada tipos de pantalla en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo todas estas medidas:

- Pantallas de 7" - mdpi
- Pantallas de 3.2" - mdpi.

Por ello intento crear directorios para cada tipo de pantalla , pero no todas responden a su respectiva descripción,  por ejemplo, en el caso de las tabletas que son de 1024px y son mdpi programé valores para values-sw320dp-mdpi,values-sw480dp-mdpi.

¿Debo hacer los mismo para todos y cada caso de pantalla? Si así fuera el caso ... ¿Cómo tendría que nombrar dichos directorio según su descripción para que estos puedan renderizarse con su respectivas medidas?

¿Cómo tendría que nombrar los archivos dimens.xml para que sean adecuados a cada tipo de pantalla?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mira este post - http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46276/programe-mis-contenido-en-un-pantalla-mdpi-de-3-2-y-me-doy-cuenta-que-hay-otra

Comment: Por favor aprende a realizar las preguntas correctamente. Una frase no se compone de mil y una comas (, ) con un punto al final. Separa bien las ideas. Además, no escribas en mayúsculas  si no es realmente necesario

Answer (score 0):

Si requieres otra medida de dimension en otra densidad, agrega el archivo dimens.xml, en el folder correspondiente de densidad  :

```
/values-sw320dp-mdpi

/values-sw480dp-mdpi
```

Y agrega la entrada correspondiente a la medida que automaticamente el sistema operativo tomará.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="mi_medida">56dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Este valor lo tomara automaticamente tu layout o vista dependiendo la densidad del dispositivo.

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/mi_medida"
```

Actualmente en Stackoverflow en español se tienen preguntas relacionadas:

- [¿Como hacer para que el texto ajuste su tamaño segun el tamaño de la pantalla en android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40896/como-hacer-para-que-el-texto-ajuste-su-tama%C3%B1o-segun-el-tama%C3%B1o-de-la-pantalla-en/40897#40897)
- [Diferentes clases para layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46253/diferentes-clases-para-layout-layout-large-layout-xlarge/46257#46257)
- [¿Cómo modificar mis pantallas dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla en android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34068/c%C3%B3mo-modificar-mis-pantallas-dependiendo-del-tama%C3%B1o-de-la-pantalla-en-android)